# Could more namespaces improve compilation time?

Tags: c++, namespaces, argument-dependent-lookup, compilation-time

I work with a very large codebase (above 3K translation units) in which almost every declaration is under the same namespace. Occasionally, some sub-namespaces are declared, but it is definitely not the rule.

I was wondering: could compilation time benefit from having more namespaces? I was thinking mostly about Koenig Lookup, but I am not sure some other compilation steps might be affected as well.

For the general topic of increase compilation time, we went for the Unity Build approach.

About namespace topic, we did not really tried anything. It would require some very specific code generation logic to try to reproduce something measurable I guess. We would go that far if I find no good answer online.

Comment: why it should improve anything? basically no. To improve build times: use forward declarations extensively (whenever you can), to avoid includes in header files. Put as little implementation in header files as possible. Note there are some implicit implementations (like destructor, constructors, assignment). Static linking increases build times.

Comment: If your build tool chains support C++20 modules this will be great time saver.

Comment: Namespaces are not there for improving performance(in terms of compilation time). They have a different purpose.

Comment: In general, using more namespaces is unlikely to significantly affect compilation time unless there are specific situations where name lookups are slowing down the compilation process.

Comment: I think one could come up with a pathological example where it does make significant impact. How pathological one has to go would be interesting to find out by experiment. How pathological your code is only you know ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using narrower namespaces may reduce the number of functions that need to be considered in overload resolution for argument-dependent lookup, however I would only in rare cases expect that to make a significant difference (e.g. if a lot of template instantiation is associated with the overload resolution).

In general I would not expect any performance impact, either positive or negative.

Comment: I also tend to think it should be fast enough, but since I am not a compiler implementer, I do not really know the implications of the single namespace approach, specially when combined with other language features such as templates, as you are mentioning.